# What material belongs on Stack Overflow Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Are we being too lax in what content we are accepting on
[Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation)?

For an example, does the topic
[Linked Lists (C-language)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/560/linked-lists#t=201611090849139383616)
really fall under "Documentation"?

Continuing with the C-language as an example: documentation in this
respect would be about dynamic memory allocation, `malloc`, `calloc`,
pointers and "the heap". Linked lists are an application of using
these functions to compose a data-structure.

In the context of the C-language linked lists isn't a topic of its
own. It is arguably a topic under the data-structure tag, but even then
I wouldn't consider
[Introduction to Algorithms (**CLRS**)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms)
and [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/) as
"documentation".

To what extent should Stack Overflow Documentation be about specific
technologies, and to what extent should it be about applications of
doing things with these technologies? Should we accept "How to write a
Sudoku Solver in Haskell"? How to implement Conway's Game of Life
in Python? And what about less tutorial-esque material such as "The
process environment in C"?

Comment: You are aware that Documentation is not about Documentation but about "examples" ?

Comment: Yes, but I still think that there are gray areas that should be addressed. For an example, my last paragraph.

Comment: The guiding philosophy for Docs seems to be "invite users to throw stuff at the wall and see what sticks" (though usually more positively stated with that story about paths in the grass at UC Irvine).  So I guess my suggestion is "paste stuff in the text box and see what gets upvoted", and worry about _where_ it should go later (Docs is designed to frustrate organization, anyway).